# navigation-animate:slide_in_left doesn't work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I set the animation:

```
slide_in_left.xml

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

```
slide_out_right.xml

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"/>
</set>
```

And I use it by

```
    <action
            ...
          
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
```

This action is:**A**->**B**

**A** contains a Recyclerview, **B** is the item.

The expectation is that when exiting from **B**, **A** will slowly slide from the left side of the screen to the middle of the screen, and **B** will slowly slide from the middle of the screen to the right side of the screen (until it is invisible).

But the result I get is: A immediately appears in the middle of the screen and **B** will slowly slide from the middle of the screen to the right side of the screen (until it is invisible).

What happened?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by uploading the version of `fragment` and `navigation`

```
def versions = [:]

versions.fragment = "1.3.3"
versions.navigation = "2.3.5"

def fragment = [:]
fragment.runtime = "androidx.fragment:fragment:${versions.fragment}"
fragment.ktx = "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:${versions.fragment}"
deps.fragment = fragment

def navigation = [:]
navigation.runtime = "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:$versions.navigation"
navigation.runtime_ktx = "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$versions.navigation"
navigation.fragment = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$versions.navigation"
navigation.fragment_ktx = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$versions.navigation"
navigation.ui = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$versions.navigation"
navigation.ui_ktx = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$versions.navigation"
navigation.safe_args_plugin = "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$versions.navigation"
deps.navigation = navigation
```